# Learning to reverse through CTF

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I am trying to learn through CTFs(capture the flag) assignments, for the record this is not an active ctf but I am using it in order to learn what I can before I go into a real one

in this certain task I need to get a flag from the assembly code I got from a bin file for stack based custom virtual machine

But no matter what I am trying to input or where I'm trying to start from, I can't get anything that looks like a flag

I feel like I got a really good understanding for how everything works and still Been sitting on this one for a while and didn't really find anything like this task to try and see what I am missing so thought maybe someone will be able to help me see either something i missed or tell me what i should learn and where in order to understand whats going on here

this is for the opcodes and the description, if you don't need the description just scroll down to the opcodes:
https://pastebin.com/hgKKkDzC

And this is the assembly code:

```
0x00: push 0x15 

0x01: push 0x68 

0x02: push 0x0f 

0x03: push 0x61 

0x04: push 0x08 

0x05: push 0x64 

0x06: push 0x08 

0x07: push 0x67 

0x08: push 0x35 

0x09: push 0x52 

0x0a: push 0x3c 

0x0b: push 0x55 

0x0c: push 0x39 

0x0d: push 0x55 

0x0e: push 0x3a 

0x0f: push 0x68 

0x10: push 0x0f 

0x11: push 0x61 

0x12: push 0x08 

0x13: push 0x64 

0x14: push 0x08 

0x15: push 0x67 

0x16: push 0x35 

0x17: push 0x52 

0x18: push 0x3c 

0x19: push 0x55 

0x1a: push 0x39 

0x1b: push 0x55 

0x1c: push 0x3a 

0x1d: push 0x68 

0x1e: push 0x3a 

0x1f: push 0x55 

0x20: push 0x0d 

0x21: push 0x76 

0x22: push 0x11 

0x23: push 0x70 

0x24: push 0x1c 

0x25: push 0x7a 

0x26: push 0x0b 

0x27: jse 

0x28: read 

0x29: push 0x0c 

0x2a: call 

0x2b: load 0x01 

0x2c: push 0x0a 

0x2d: push 0x00 

0x2e: sub 

0x2f: cje 

0x30: push 0x30 

0x31: push 0x01 

0x32: jmp 

0x33: push 0x31 

0x34: write 

0x35: push 0x2f 

0x36: jmp 

0x37: load 0x02 

0x38: load 0x02 

0x39: push 0x00 

0x3a: push 0x25 

0x3b: cje 

0x3c: load 0x02 

0x3d: swap 0x01 

0x3e: push 0x00 

0x3f: push 0x20 

0x40: cje 

0x41: push 0x00 

0x42: swap 0x01 

0x43: load 0x04 

0x44: push 0x1b 

0x45: cje 

0x46: pop 

0x47: push 0x02 

0x48: load 0x02 

0x49: div 

0x4a: push 0x02 

0x4b: load 0x05 

0x4c: div 

0x4d: swap 0x01 

0x4e: swap 0x02 

0x4f: add 

0x50: push 0x02 

0x51: swap 0x01 

0x52: div 

0x53: swap 0x01 

0x54: pop 

0x55: load 0x02 

0x56: load 0x02 

0x57: push 0x24 

0x58: push 0x00 

0x59: sub 

0x5a: call 

0x5b: push 0x02 

0x5c: mul 

0x5d: add 

0x5e: swap 0x02 

0x5f: pop 

0x60: pop 

0x61: swap 0x03 

0x62: pop 

0x63: swap 0x01 

0x64: pop 

0x65: ret
```

Comment: figured out something stupid i was doing, involving subtracting by zero, forgot it gives a negative number

going to try and do it the right way now and hope i figure the right input from the get go